# How wicket LoadableDetachable model works

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to understand how Wicket LoadableDetachable model is working.
What i understand from the Wicket documentation is in a normal scenario , when the request completes the processing wicket will auto serialize the all components with associated model values. This one will consumes more memory . If we use the LoadableDetachable model at the time of serialization the model values will not get serialized. Is this right? . So it will detach the model object automatically . So For the next request the model value will be reload again automatically? See my below code.

```
public class ProductListPanel extends Column<Product> {

    @SpringBean
    private ProductService productService;
    private List productList;


    public ProductListPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
        class ProductModel extends LoadableDetachableModel {

            @Override
            public void detach() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                productList = null;
                System.out.print("Called Detach Object\n");
            }


            @Override
            protected Object load() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                productList = productService.findAll();
                System.out.print("Called Get Object\n");
                return productList;
            }

        }
        System.out.print("Before creating also calling\n");
        final ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();

        ListView view = new ListView("list", productModel) {

            protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
                System.out.print("\nBefore start also calling\n");
                System.out.print("Before this one is callling \n");
                Product result = (Product) item.getModelObject();
                item.add(new Label("code", result.getCode()));
                item.add(new Label("name", result.getName()));
                final Link deleteLink = new Link("remove", item.getModel()) {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick() {
                        Product product = (Product) getModelObject();
                        productService.delete(product);

                    }

                };
                item.add(deleteLink);

            }
        };

        add(view);
        Link addProductLink = new Link("addProduct") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setResponsePage(new AddProduct());
            }

        };
        add(addProductLink);
        productModel.detach();
    }
}
```

In the above code i am listing all the products from the DB. and i am having Remove link for each product , when we are clicking that link i am removing the product from the DB. After clicking the Remove link the page is not getting refreshed means it still showing the deleted product . if i add this line  productModel.detach(); then it is working properly . My question here is why i have to call  productModel.detach(); manually? LoadableDetachableModel suppose do automatically right?

Please help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LoadableDetachableModel` caches the retrieved object for the duration it is attached. When you `load` the data from the database, all items are there. Then you execute a query to delete a record, but don't update the list. So either you have to change your `onClick` handler to **also** update the retrieved list, or just detach the model.

There is no magic in LoadableDetachableModel. Take a look at the code below:

```
List<Person> people = dao.getListOfPeopleAttendingParty();

// assume that the number of people attending the party is 4
assert people.size() == 4;

Person guest = people.get(0);
dao.delete(guest);

// what is the number of people attending the party now?
assert people.size() == ?;
```

What do you think that `people.size()` is now?

The execution of LoadableDetachableModel is not any different than the code snippet above:

```
List<Person> people = peopleModel.getObject(); // is called by ListView

// assume that the number of people attending the party is 4
assert people.size() == 4;

Person guest = people.get(0);
dao.delete(guest);

// what is the number of people attending the party now?
assert people.size() == ?;
```

So: no magic involved, just plain Java and ordinary logic.

PS. *The answer to both questions is **4** even though the database no longer holds the guest*

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer . Still i am not clear , As per loadabledetachablemodel it will detach the Component model values right. So in my first request i loaded all the products and my first request execution finished . So my productList detached already . When i am clicking the Remove link a new request will be generated and it will delete the record first then after the ListView will reload again by calling the getObject again . Is this correct? Please make me clear . Thanks again

Comment: How do you think the Link retrieves the object that needs to be deleted? (I'm not being snarky, but rather try to give you the revelation of how the parts work together)

Comment: Try having a look at the sourcecode of loadabledetachablemodel. If you are not sure how wicket is doing things just read through the source. This is the best thing you can do to understand the framework